# Is it possible to share modules and files with multiple Lua states to reduce memory usage?

Tags: c, lua, zephyr-rtos

**Setup**
I am using an STM32 microcontroller with Zephyr-RTOS. Lua is running in multiple different threads and each thread has its own Lua state.

**Problem**
The problem is that all VMs need the same modules. Each module is then multiple times in RAM, and I get the error message that there is not enough memory
Currently I check with the Lua GC how much memory is used in a VM:

```
int usage = lua_gc(lua_VM, LUA_GCCOUNT, NULL);
```

The mainVM (which starts all other lua VMs) needs roughly 30KB and the next VM about 180KB (after loading some files). I can not get any other VMs to run (not enough memory). The firmware itself needs:

```
   FLASH:      236540 B      384 KB      60.16%
     RAM:       62396 B      320 KB      19.04%
```

All Lua files are precompiled with Luac and have together a size of 331509 Byte. I read [here](https://yk-lab.org:666/shizuku/lua-api/lua-api-en-us/Tips/Memory%20Usage.html) that precompiling should help to limit memory usage.

**Question**
Is it possible to load some modules and files used by all VMs (e.g. string, table, or package) globally so that all Lua states can access them without loading them individually, thus reducing memory usage? I am new to Lua and C and would appreciate any help.

Comment: In other words, you want to make `string`, `table`, etc. standard tables read-only and shared between multiple VMs?  Lua does not have such possibility out-of-the-box.

Comment: If it is not possible out-of-the box, what would be a workaround? Or is there maybe a different way to make memory usage smaller?

Comment: The standard Lua modules are C libraries and so should not appear multiple times in your program. Only the tables that convert names to functions are duplicated. Any strings sent to Lua too.

Comment: @lhf what I am more concerned about is the duplication of external lua files/modules (which I load in with `require`) in RAM.